# Firefox Flickers on some sites after latest update

Tags: firefox

Firefox has started flickering on some sites after the last update. I am not sure if this is a Firefox or Ubuntu issue.  It did it on new Reddit when I had to go there (I use old Reddit as new is dire.)

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such issue, I haven't noticed any bug reports on the issue, but you've provided no release, kernel stack (if LTS release), or video driver issue that maybe related to your issue. I don't see a question here that anyone can actually answer except provide *opinions*

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, latest firefox. Intel video driver (built into laptop)